# Why would the "real" time be much higher than the "user" and "sys" times combined?

Tags: time, time-utility

I execute and `time` many commands (i.e. `nslookup`) through `SSH` and I collect the total time needed for the implied service to complete (i.e. **DNS**). So I collect the `user` and `sys` time as the `real` time counts time when my process is blocking which I do not need...I guess.

But some of my tests had results as such:

```
real 3m22.033s
user 0m0.009s
sys 0m0.014s
```

I execute these tests on limited resources linux boxes but still, the `real` time is significantly high. Would this only indicate that the box is VERY busy running different processes ? Is it still correct to add up the `user` and `sys` times to know how much the service took ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

*Real* is the total time it took for the process to terminate (that is difference between starting time and stopping time) :

```
$ time sleep 3

real    0m3.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

In this listing, *user* and *sys* refer to the time spent respectively in user mode and kernel mode. These **do not include** the time spent while being inactive, in ***sleeping*** state. A process goes sleeping when it deliberately requested it, or when it's waiting for IO (networking/disk access/user interaction) to be available, or waiting for other processes to terminate, for lack of CPU available when the system is under very high load, etc.

Typically, if you call `time` on `wget`, *real* will correspond to the time the download takes, *user* should be negligible (unless `wget` is asked to perform intensive data processing), *sys* should be small (some time might be spent to deal with buffers, moving data back and forth from kernel space to user space.)

Comment: I'm sorry I added `wget` to the question, I actually don't `time` it but thanks for the explanation though. Saying that `real` includes blocking times such as waiting for network IO makes me think to include that time too because I'm actually testing the network. Thank you.

Comment: Would you please confirm the following, to test the network's performance and the responsiveness of the queried machine whether it's a `DNS` server or a pinged machine, is it sufficient to only measure the `real` time ?

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana: This *real time* is just a stopwatch, nothing more. If you let `ping` run for 3 minutes 22, it will return 3 minutes 22. It's just useless in this case (and actually it's useless as a benchmark most of the time, the result depends on external factors).

Comment: thanks. But would you know why it didn't timeout ? I read that the default timeout for `nslookup` is 5 seconds !

Comment: The `wget` part of the answer is interesting and inspiring. For others, here's my `time wget xx` [output](https://pastebin.com/GnZ2LDE5)